# Call stack exceeded when using react-router in an auth pattern

Tags: react-router

I'm using `react-router rc6` in the following auth pattern:

```
const isLoggedIn = false

function requireAuth (nextState, replaceState) {
  console.log(nextState.location.pathname)
  if(!isLoggedIn) {
    replaceState({ nextPathName: nextState.location.pathname }, '/login')
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Main} onEnter={requireAuth}>
      <Route path='login' component={Login} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

I've seen this as a common pattern, but according to https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2773, I can't redirect in an `onEnter` hook because the function `requireAuth` above gets called in an infinite loop. How should I do it instead? I want to redirect to the `/login` page if not authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `/` `onEnter` handler tries to redirect to a route that executes the same `/` `onEvent` handler.

I.e. what happens is:

1. Router tries to handle request to `/` (first match of `/login`).
2. `/` has an `onEnter` handler. Handler is executed.
3. Handler wants to navigate to `/login`.
4. Router tries to handle request to `/` (back to step 1).

So as you can see, the reason why you are getting a call stack exceeded error is because it is circular.

Try to change your routes to the following:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Main}>
      <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
      <Route path='/user' onEnter={requireAuth}>
        <Route path='/profile' component={Profile}>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

This way only the routes that require authentication are protected behind your `requireAuth` handler.

If you'd rather have a simple auth solution for React, take a look at the [React SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react) for [Stormpath](http://www.stormpath.com/) that I've built.

It will take care of all of this. And instead of having to use hacky `onEnter` handlers, all you need to do is use the SDK's `AuthenticatedRoute`. E.g.

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
  <HomeRoute path='/' component={MasterPage}>
    <IndexRoute component={IndexPage} />
    <LoginRoute path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
    <LogoutRoute path='/logout' />
    <Route path='/verify' component={VerifyEmailPage} />
    <Route path='/register' component={RegisterPage} />
    <Route path='/forgot' component={ResetPasswordPage} />
    <AuthenticatedRoute>
      <HomeRoute path='/profile' component={ProfilePage} />
    </AuthenticatedRoute>
  </HomeRoute>
</Router>
```

The example above is a real-world example extracted from the [React SDK example project](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express-react-example). See: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express-react-example/blob/master/src/app.js#L11-L23.

Let me know if this helped you.